# Bullet proof way to avoid jquery conflicts on wordpress plugins

Tags: wordpress, plugins, conflict, jquery

I have been developing wordpress plugins for a while now and i always seem to get the following issues with all my plugins Jquery conflicts issues.

I have tried so many different ways to avoid these but i always get users contacting me saying when they have installed one off my plugins it has stopped another plugin from working aahhhhh.

I really want to get this sorted because i understand how frustrating this can be for people.

I always set and option or include wordpresses jquery, below is just an example not working code.

```
add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'include_jquery' ) );

function include_jquery(){

                   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
                   wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"), false, '1.7.1');
                   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

            }
```

Ok so after issues with this i now have a select option in the plugin admin to toggle yes or no to include jquery or not i know it is automatically installed but some users remove this, this works for some people but not all.

if you include the wordpress jquery i know you have to run your jquery with the following.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
```

jQuery instead of the dollar sign $

i understand and have used jquery no conflict and tried and tested some if not all off these 
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

```
$.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
```

This as with the others works for some but not all users with conflicts arising still with certain users.

I am hoping that from this post some of us wordpress plugin developers could help out and post a bullet proof way to use wordpress and jquery within our plugins without getting conflict issues.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doesn't it work with a closure?

```
(function($){
    // your plugin code
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This definitely works, I don't get the hustle in the question? Add a window and undefined as self invoking function's arguments, and your good to go!

Answer (score 1):

Read these parts of the codex :

- [Load a default WordPress script from a non-default location](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Load_a_default_WordPress_script_from_a_non-default_location)
- [jQuery noConflict wrappers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers)

You should use `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook instead of `init`.

And you should use `jQuery.noConflict();` instead of `$.noConflict();`.

Comment: great thanks for the reply going to look at these and report back