# Simple jquery animation on click does not work in wordpress website

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-animate

This makes me nervous...

I would like that my two menu lists (**`<ul id="cont1">`** and **`<ul id="cont2">`**) move when we click on **.bttn1** and **.bttn2**. They are on the sidebar. One of them is hidden by the menu div :

**HTML in a text widget :**

```
<div id="menu">

    <div class="bttn1">Pages public</div>
    <div class="bttn2">Pages communauté</div>

    <div id="cont">
        <ul id="cont1">
            <li class="n01">01</li>  
            <li class="n02" id="page9">
                <a href="http://www.igorlaszlo.com/test/">
                    <img src="images/icon1.png" alt="accueil" />
                    <p>Accueil</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="n03"></li>
            <li class="n04"></li>
            <li class="n05" id="page11">
                <a href="http://www.igorlaszlo.com/test/register/">
                    <img src="images/icon2.png" alt="abonnement" />
                    <p>Inscription</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            ...
        </ul>

        <ul id="cont2">
            <li class="n01">10</li>
            <li class="n02" id="page23">
                <a href="http://www.igorlaszlo.com/test/members/">
                    <img src="images/icon10.png" alt="communauté" />
                    <p>Liste Membres</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="n03"></li>
            <li class="n04"></li>
            <li class="n05" id="page25">
            ...
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The CSS**

```
#menu {
    width: 242px;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#menu .bttn1,
#menu .bttn2 {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 2%;
    line-height: 30px !important;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fdfdfd;
    background: #ce2d32;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    -webkit-transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(5deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(5deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(5deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(5deg);
    transform:rotate(5deg); 
}
#menu #cont {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
    height: 550px;
}
#menu #cont1 {top: 0;left: 0;}
#menu #cont2 {top: 0;left: 252px;}
#menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 242px;
    height: 450px;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

I have a wordpress test website which includes already a default jquery file. 
I place the following code in the footer.php just before the closing /body tag :

```
... 

<?php wp_footer(); ?>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#menu #cont1').css('left',0);
        $('#menu #cont2').css('left','252px');

        $('#menu .bttn1').click(function(){
            $('#menu #cont1').delay(300).animate({'left':'-252px'},800,'easeInOut');
            $('#menu #cont2').delay(500).animate({'left':0},800,'easeInOut');
        });
        $('#menu .bttn2').click(function(){
            $('#menu #cont1').delay(500).animate({'left':0},800,'easeInOut');
            $('#menu #cont2').delay(300).animate({'left':'252px'},800,'easeInOut');
        });

    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It does not work and i do not find the problem. I tried to add the code into the head.php too, it does not move at all...

The test site : http://www.igorlaszlo.com/test/

The question is, what is wrong with above code or how can i test if something blocks the script ?

Comment: ok, what i see is that i must correct the $ to jQuery in the code, so like this i can see in Firebug that the css is applied to the cont1 and cont2... what else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the solution is simple and you could have seen it if you checked the console.

```
TypeError: $ is not a function
```

So insted of using `$` for jQuery use `jQuery`.
Also where are no `easeInOut` in the current loaded jQuery so load jQueryUi

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Final javascript code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#menu #cont1').css('left',0);
    jQuery('#menu #cont2').css('left','252px');

    jQuery('#menu .bttn1').click(function(){
        jQuery('#menu #cont1').delay(300).animate({'left':'-252px'},800,'easeInOut');
        jQuery('#menu #cont2').delay(500).animate({'left':0},800,'easeInOut');
    });
    jQuery('#menu .bttn2').click(function(){
        jQuery('#menu #cont1').delay(500).animate({'left':0},800,'easeInOut');
        jQuery('#menu #cont2').delay(300).animate({'left':'252px'},800,'easeInOut');
    });
});
```

** EDIT **
I think you found your error.

Comment: thanks a lot... i found just some seconds before your answer that i must correct the $ to jQuery... i did not understand the second part of your answer, jqueryui.js is loaded : `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.igorlaszlo.com/test/wp-content/plugins/wp-symposium/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js?ver=4.0'></script>` in the html code source. But anyway, i disabled the transition effect, it works, thanks a lot... however it works the opposite than i wanted, i will correct it :))) thanks again !

Comment: just for information, i loaded jquery-ui.min.js as you said, i readded the 'easeinout' effect, it does not work like this...

Comment: Ok, any way the width is quite small so the 'easeinout' is ok to be removed. Nice page by the way.

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of things you can do to troubleshoot the issue. First make sure your code works correctly outside of Word Press. You can recreate what you are trying to do in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to make sure your JS is working correctly.

Once you get that working correctly add it to your Word Press website. If you're having problems check to make sure your using the correct version of JQuery (older versions may cause issues) You should also make sure to disable your plugins when testing to make sure there is no JavaScript conflicts.

Lastly you need to set a JQuery no conflict for WordPress like this:

```
(function($){
    // your plugin code
})(jQuery);
```

You can reference this [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12348168/bullet-proof-way-to-avoid-jquery-conflicts-on-wordpress-plugins).

Comment: yes, thanks crazymatt, i forgot that wp conflict with jquery but i found it some minutes ago, just like Thanasis... the other problem was the transition effect (see Thanasis' answer) !