# How to display posts carousel, not working

Tags: wordpress, themes, carousel, slick.js

Not Working 'posts carousel' in my Wordpress website.
In my theme, the 'Posts Carousel' function is not working.
I thought it might be a plugin problem, so I can't see it even if I turn off all plugins.

But when I use the WordPress default theme, 'Posts Carousel' is worked.

All 4 plugins for 'Posts Carousel' are not worked the same.

Could you help me?

I'm so stressed out by this part, and if the deadline is approaching and I can't fix it, I have to start all the projects again.
[image]
https://knock-em.com/home-new/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an conflicts jquery
The following links can help you

1. [jquery conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12348168/bullet-proof-way-to-avoid-jquery-conflicts-on-wordpress-plugins)
2. [Load a default WordPress script from a non-default location](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Load_a_default_WordPress_script_from_a_non-default_location)
3. [jQuery noConflict wrappers](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers)